# AngularJS set global ngModelOptions

Tags: angularjs, configuration, angular-ngmodel

The default behaviour for updating ngModel (and subsequently validation) is on *change*; I would like to change that to on *blur*. The [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) only explain how to do this on a case-by-case basis via: `<ANY ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"></ANY>`. I went so far as to look thru the source code, but somehow neither *ngModelOptions* nor *ng-model-options* is found (despite both occurring in the documentation, which is scraped from the source code).

Comment: whenever I run into stuff like this I create my own directive that returns template with the various attributes needed

Comment: @charlietfl, I thought of that, but it's a workaround. I'd prefer a proper solution, if possible. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Its in the angular source in input.js: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2657

Comment: As stated in `NgModelOptions` documentation, `ngModelOptions` directive is applied to the element it's declared on **and it's descendants**.

so it's pretty safe to apply it on a tag like `<body>` and assume that it'll be applied to all child elements.

Comment: Update on blur causes problems for radio and checkboxes when applied to the entire form.  Instead use debounce like this `ng-model-options="{ debounce : { default : 500, blur : 0 } }"`

Answer (score 25):

While the `ngModel` decorators written by Jon/John provide a good behind the scene solution, one must also be aware that declaratively, `ngModelOptions` need not have to be declared at the individual input field level but can be declared at the module level.

```
<body ng-app = "myApp" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

Doing the above would have all the input fields in `myApp` module inherit the ng-model-options.
These can then be overriden in specific input fields if required (eg. search filters).

This plunker demonstrates: http://plnkr.co/edit/2L1arGgHJwK82xVucJ4p?p=preview

Comment: I like this a lot better except that it applies to everything including input types that are not optimal like selects, checkboxes, and such. Seems we're just flipping from manually enabling blur option on textboxes to manually enabling default option on non-textboxes. I suppose if you have a lot more textboxes than other controls this is a slight improvement...

Comment: For our team, we constantly get burned by the default option of 'false' for 'allowInvalid'. Setting it at the application level saves a lot of issues when we unexpectedly get model properties being set to 'undefined' when determined invalid (which doesn't feel intuitive to us).

Comment: See I've known about the model invalidation issue in AngularJS, but somehow wasnt aware that ngModelOptions allows handling that. Thanks for commenting in. And i totally agree that its un-intuitive - spoke more about that in an AngularJS git issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2743#issuecomment-61847365).

Answer (score 23):

As @Angad mentions you can set ng-model-options on *any* element, and it will be **applied to all its descendants**. However, the problem with this is that if you set it like this, radios and checkboxes stop working as expected:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

This can be circumvented by adding `change` and `click` to the `updateOn`:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change click blur' }">
```

If you would also want to update after a certain delay after typing you could use the following:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'keyup change click blur', debounce: { keyup: 500, click: 0, change: 0, blur: 0 } }">
```

I tested these techniques in Firefox, Chome, Internet Explorer (10, 11) and Safari. If you use other events then these, be sure to test it cross browser, for example radios fire `change` directly after clicking, on all browsers except IE.

Comment: Also worth noting: You can also set `ng-model-options` on a specific element to override the parent element's configuration. So you could set `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default' }"` on a checkbox to get it back to normal. (at least in chrome)

Answer (score 12):

This is a really good question so I've written a more indepth [blog article about this](http://www.jonsamwell.com/angularjs-set-default-blur-behaviour-on-ngmodeloptions/). The only real generic way I have come up with to do this is to decorate the ngModel directive as it is this directive that really uses the ngModelOptions.

If you look at the angular source for the [ngModel](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2154) directive it has a pre link function to effectively setup the ngModelOptions on the ngModelController through the use of the property $options.  Note the $options is created in the ngModelOptionsDirective which is effectively a $eval on the ng-model-options attribute.

What we need to do in our ngModel dectorator is after this pre link function add a default value for this $options property if it is undefined.  I am assuming here that if the developer has explicitly set the ngModelOptions in your project that they don't want it magically changed!  Therefore we will only set the defaults if the $options property is undefined.

Here is the code:

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('myAppOverridesModule').config(['$provide',
    function ($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', [
            '$delegate',
            function ($delegate) {
                var directive = $delegate[0],
                    link = directive.link,
                    shouldSetBlurUpdateEvent = function (nodeName, inputType) {
                        // The blur event is only really applicable to input controls so
                        // we want to stick with the default events for selects, checkboxes & radio buttons
                        return nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'textarea' ||
                               (nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && 
                               inputType.toLowerCase() !== 'checkbox' && 
                               inputType.toLowerCase() !== 'radio');
                    };

                directive.compile = function () {
                    return function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                        var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
                        link.pre.apply(this, arguments);

                        // if ngModelOptions is specified leave it unmodified as developer is explicitly setting it.
                        if (ngModelCtrl.$options === undefined && shouldSetBlurUpdateEvent(element[0].nodeName, element[0].type)) {
                            console.log('set');
                            ngModelCtrl.$options = {
                                updateOn: 'blur',
                                updateOnDefault: false
                            };
                        }

                        link.post.apply(this, arguments);
                    };
                };

                return $delegate;
            }
        ]);
    }
]);
}(angular));
```

UPDATE: I've updated the code to ignore selects, checkboxes & radio buttons as the blur event is not the optimal update event for them.

Comment: Cool - let me know if anything with it is not working as expected :-)

Comment: Oh darn—I just realised `ngModelOptions` is still in beta :(

Comment: You could always use my validation module which supports ngModelOptions in angular 1.2 and below to allow validation on blur. http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/

Comment: I think the answer is outdated, the angular code has changed.

Answer (score 5):

I modified Jon Samwell's answer because I couldn't get his to work anymore.

This overrides the ngModelDirective's compile function by storing a reference to it then returning the pre/postLink functions w/ calls to their originals plus our extra override code.

Enjoy!

```
app.config(function($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0],
            link = directive.link,
            shouldSetBlurUpdateEvent = function (nodeName, inputType) {
              // The blur event is only really applicable to input controls so
              // we want to stick with the default events for selects, checkboxes & radio buttons
              return nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'textarea' ||
                    (nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && 
                     inputType.toLowerCase() !== 'checkbox' && 
                     inputType.toLowerCase() !== 'radio');
                };

        // save a reference to the original compile function
        var compileFn = directive.compile;

        directive.compile = function () {   

            var link = compileFn.apply(this, arguments);

            return {
                pre: function ngModelPostLink(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {

                    if(!ctrls[2]) {
                        ctrls[2] = {};
                    }

                    var ngModelOptions = ctrls[2];

                    if (ngModelOptions.$options === undefined && shouldSetBlurUpdateEvent(element[0].nodeName, element[0].type)) {
                        ngModelOptions.$options = {
                            updateOn: 'blur',
                            updateOnDefault: false
                        };
                    }

                    link.pre.apply(this, arguments);
                },
                post: link.post
            };
        };

        return $delegate;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }
```

you could use

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce : { default : 500 } }"
```

and apply it to a parent element in the dom, such as a container div.  The `debounce` setting above tells Angular to only evaluate the validation rules after 500 milliseconds of no activity.

Using `debounce` this way is superior to using `blur` because blur creates problems for radio and checkboxes when applied to the entire form.

The debounce option is an integer value which causes the model update to delay an integer number of milliseconds.  It reduces the frequency of `$digest` cycles occurring, which causes the js application to consume less resources as well as allowing the user time to type before validation rules are applied.

[YearOfMoo.com](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html) recomends using blur and debounce together like this

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce : { default : 500, blur : 0 } }"
```

Now model value and validations are applied immediately after the user blurs out of the field. This sets a wait time of 0 ms for the blur event.  Blur overrides the default value.