# Tell Angular not to refresh the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm building an angular app.

I need to listen to the `onKeyDown` event (especially the ESC event) in order to close a sidebar.
But when I do, it seems to view is refresh at every key pressed which is annoying because I have random colors on the page that changes every time.

index.html :

```html
<body ng-keydown="onKeyDown">
    ...
</body>
```

and in js :

```js
$rootScope.onKeyDown = function ($event) {
    if ($event.keyCode == 27) {
        $rootScope.sidebar = false 
    }
    /*
    else {
         //please don't refresh the scope
    }
    */
}
```

Is it normal, and how to avoid angular to refresh the page when nothing change?

Comment: Angular's best practices require that the getters of ViewModel properties are fast and idempotent. Your random color should not be refreshed every time there is a $digest cycle

Comment: @NewDev, I agree it's not the best practice but it's was the quikest one : `style="background: {{ color() }}"`. I don't know how to do otherwise (it has to be js-side, no css).

Comment: That's fine. What I mean is that `color()` should return the same value regardless of the number of times you call it. If this doesn't work, create another method, like `lastGeneratedColor()`.

Comment: My present solution is : `color()` simply return a random string value stored in a list and does nothing else. `return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]`
I'll keep this as it is. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `ng-keydown` attr, I've switch to binding `keydown` event on `$document` in `app.run()` which:

1. works and
2. is I think cleaner that adding `ng-keydown` on body.

```
$document.bind('keydown', function ($event) {
    if ($event.keyCode == 27) {
        $rootScope.sidebar = false;
        $rootScope.$digest()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable the default event that triggers a $scope digest on every keystroke using [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Ex.

```
// This disables the INPUT from triggering digests 
<input ng-model="someModel" ng-model-options="{updateOn:''}" ng-keydown="update($event)">

// manually check and trigger a $digest
$scope.update = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 27) {
    $scope.$digest();
  }
}
```

If you want to do this globally then you need to configure your application (rather than apply ng-model-options to every input on the page).  See [AngularJS set global ngModelOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707508/angularjs-set-global-ngmodeloptions/26537212#26537212).

There are certainly more elegant solutions to do this but they require a lot of source diving and ninja skills.  Hence why, people get frustrated with Angular.

Comment: Hi @JohnStrickler, it seems to do not work because I'm doing it on the body element. Here my body tag : `<body ng-model="lol" ng-model-options="{updateOn:''}" ng-keydown="onKeyDown">`

Comment: This version doesn't work too : `<body ng-model="lol" ng-model-options="{updateOn:''}" ng-keydown="onKeyDown($event)">`