# How to prevent data loss due to navigation when using Angular debounce?

Tags: angularjs, debouncing

I recently became familiar with Angular's debounce feature.  The use case I have for debounce is that I want to save (server-side) what the user is typing as he types, but I don't want to have an HTTP request for every single keystroke.  Giving my form a debounce value of 500 allows for the data to be saved when the user stops typing for half a second without having to click a [Save] button.  This is very convenient.

However, there is a disadvantage I've discovered.  Especially if the debounce value is high (which I may want it to be depending on the size of the payload), there is a chance that the user may navigate away from the page before the data is saved.

In the above example, the user might type "Hello!", wait half a second, and then type "Great to meet you!", and then navigate to another page or close the browser before the debounce period expires.  (This is not far-fetched, especially if the text input is near navigation controls.)  In this case, "Hello!" gets saved, but "Great to meet you!" gets lost.

I've seen pages (usually pages full of ads) that fire obnoxious Javascript when you navigate away from the page, so I was wondering if Angular has some functionality to do whatever would have happened when the debounce period expired when the user leaves the page.

Of course, I realize that there are some exceptional circumstances, such as power loss, that will still result in data loss no matter what!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional triggers such as `updateOn` can be used in conjunction with `debounce` in order to fine tune behavior.

In the example below, the text from the input field will be bound to the model every 500ms, however it's also bound immediately once the user navigates away from the field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 }}">
<p>Hello {{myModel}}!</p>
```

Here we're overriding the `default` behavior of the input field, which wants to update the model on every keystroke.

Additional resources: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dhVl9mtqiE4APQmP9MOQ

Comment: That's a good start.  The event will definitely fire when the user moves the focus away from the text area, but what if I want to do both.  Suppose that the user is to enter a very large amount of text and we want to debounce it, but also be sure to save it if the user navigates away?

Comment: Good point, just updated the answer/plunker. Angular lets us combine triggers in order to get more granular behavior, which is nice.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @lux.  One more thing I'd like to know: if there are multiple inputs on a page, is there a straight-forward wait to apply these settings to all of them?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Here's a good question for that, with a decent answer. Personally I'd just write a directive that manually adds `ngModelOptions` attributes, but it looks as though you can go even more global, byoutright decorating `ngModel`, seems like overkill, but it's definitely an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707508/angularjs-set-global-ngmodeloptions